# Make Animation Play After Boolean is Set to True?

Tags: c#, animation, boolean, unity-game-engine

I am pretty fluent in using Unity, but regarding Mechanim and Animations I am not the too great at currently, so please don't give me too much of a hard time lol. So I have this boolean that is in my GameManager script:

```
public bool countDownDone = false;
```

This boolean gets set to true once my "3,2,1, GO!" Countdown Timer ends at the beginning of my game. Everything in my game starts after that boolean is set to true. Example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlaneMover : MonoBehaviour {

    private GameManagerScript GMS; // Reference to my GameManager Script

    public float scrollSpeed;
    public float tileSizeZAxis;
    public float acceleration; //This has to be a negative number in the inspector. Since our plane is coming down.

    private Vector3 startPosition;

    void Start () {

        GMS = GameObject.Find ("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManagerScript> (); //Finds the Script at the first frame

        // Transform position of the quad
        startPosition = transform.position;
    }

    void Update () {

        if (GMS.countDownDone == true) //Everything starts once the countdown ends. 
        {

            /* Every frame - time in the game times the assigned scroll speed 
                and never exceed the length of the tile that we assign */
            float newPosition = Mathf.Repeat (Time.time * scrollSpeed, tileSizeZAxis);

            // New position equal to the start position plus vector3forward times new position
            transform.position = startPosition + Vector3.forward * newPosition; // was vector3.forward

            scrollSpeed += Time.deltaTime * acceleration; // This makes the plane increase in speed over time with
                                                          // whatever our acceleration is set to.

        }
    }
}
```

I have this Crawling animation that plays at the very beginning of the game (Even before the Timer ends) and loops forever. My question is , how do I make that crawling animation also start once that boolean is set to "true"? Or do I just apply it to a CoRoutine and make it play after 3 seconds? I have done extensive research on whether to reference Animation or Animator and I got confused on that too. Any advice? If you need more pictures or details on my question, just let me know. Thank you! :)

[image]

[image: animation state]

[image]

NEW CODE BELOW

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Crawling : MonoBehaviour {

    Animator animator;

    private GameManagerScript GMS;

    void Start () 
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();

        GMS = GameObject.Find ("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManagerScript> ();

    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if (GMS.countDownDone == true) 
        {
            animator.Play("Main Character Crawling", 1);
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have this Crawling animation that plays at the very beginning of the
>   game (Even before the Timer ends) and loops forever. My question is ,
>   how do I make that crawling animation also start once that boolean is
>   set to "true"?

The solution is to play the animation from script.
Remove the current`Animation`.

Select the GameObject your `PlaneMover` script is attached to, attach Animation and `Animator` components to it. Make sure that the Animation's `Play Automatically` is unchecked.

```
public class PlaneMover : MonoBehaviour {
private GameManagerScript GMS; // Reference to my GameManager Script

    public float scrollSpeed;
    public float tileSizeZAxis;
    public float acceleration; //This has to be a negative number in the inspector. Since our plane is coming down.

    private Vector3 startPosition;

    Animation animation;
    public AnimationClip animationClip; //Assign from Editor

    void Start () {

        GMS = GameObject.Find ("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManagerScript> (); //Finds the Script at the first frame

        // Transform position of the quad
        startPosition = transform.position;

        animation = GetComponent<Animation>();

        //Add crawing Animation
        animation.AddClip(animationClip, "Crawling");
        //Add other animation clips here too if there are otheres
    }

    void Update () 
    {

        if (GMS.countDownDone) //Everything starts once the countdown ends. 
        {

            /* Every frame - time in the game times the assigned scroll speed 
                and never exceed the length of the tile that we assign */
            float newPosition = Mathf.Repeat (Time.time * scrollSpeed, tileSizeZAxis);

            // New position equal to the start position plus vector3forward times new position
            transform.position = startPosition + Vector3.forward * newPosition; // was vector3.forward

            scrollSpeed += Time.deltaTime * acceleration; // This makes the plane increase in speed over time with
                                                          // whatever our acceleration is set to.

            //Play Animation
            animation.PlayQueued("Crawling", QueueMode.CompleteOthers);
        }
    }
} }
```

Comment: is it safe to use Legacy Animations in Unity now? I read about how they are trying to phase that out and go completely with Mechanim (Animator). In order for me to use what you kindly provided me, I have to change my animation clip to the Legacy format :) @Programmer

Comment: @StephenGeorge You are right. That is old but Unity will not remove it anytime soon because lots of projects are still using it. I just check on Unity's website and it will wont be removed anytime soon. It is recommended that you use the new Animator API.

Comment: @StephenGeorge It is almost the-same thing with my answer. Simple remove the Animation API in my answer and replace it with Animator. To play it use `Animator.Play("stateName")`. `stateName` is the name of animation state created in Mechanim.

Comment: Okay thank you for clarifying that it is best to stick with the Animator API! @Programmer

Comment: How do I show you my new code in a comment?? @Programmer

Comment: @StephenGeorge Put **Edit** at the end of your question then add your new code and also tell me what's wrong with it. I haven't worked with mechanim but will see what I can do.

Comment: @StephenGeorge Do it in your question not in my answer.

Comment: @StephenGeorge that's fine. I rejected the edit. What's happening now? Does it work? Any error?

Comment: There are no errors, but with the "NEW CODE" I posted below my question, it still has yet to work. My character does not do the animation at all. @Programmer

Comment: I solved the problem, but I could not have done it without the principles you showed me. I am going to mark your answer as correct since you took the time to help me anyways and you were correct in your logistics. Thank you!! :) @Programmer

Comment: @StephenGeorge You are welcome. I was just messing with Animator to see if I can figure it out. Will take time off this week to learn mechanim. I don't like the enable and disable stuff. You can setbool to true in Animation. Please watch this from Unity on how to set it up. It will be useful you in the future. https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/animate-anything-mecanim

Comment: Oh yeah! I have watched that video a few times before for other types of animation in my game, but it never dawned on me to look at it again for setting Booleans (which is exactly what I need lol). Thank you for your wisdom. @Programmer

Comment: @StephenGeorge Yup I think that is what you need. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem!! 
This is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Crawling : MonoBehaviour {

    public Animator animator;

    private GameManagerScript GMS;

    void Start () 
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();

        GMS = GameObject.Find ("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManagerScript> ();

    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if (GMS.countDownDone == true) {
            animator.enabled = true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            animator.enabled = false;
        }
    }   
}
```

All I do is just enable the Animator that I attach in the Inspector whenever "countDownDone" becomes "true", and for added safety, I added the "else" for it to be disabled. If someone notices a way for me to improve this script, please let me know. Thank you :)

Shorter version:

```
if (GMS.countDownDone) 
 animator.enabled = true; 
 else 
animator.enabled = false;
```

Comment: Since `countDownDone` is bool, you can just do if(GMS.countDownDone). Also since you are only running one command in if and else statement, you can can shorten it by removing both `{}`. So now you have `if (GMS.countDownDone) 
            animator.enabled = true;
        else 
            animator.enabled = false;`

Comment: Thank you for your improvements :) @Programmer